# Remove www in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have SSL secure website. I set following in .htaccess in order to always open https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} OFF
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It works fine, except the situation when somebody type www.mydomain.com, then chrome prints error with certificate.

Any suggestions how to change rewrite settings?

Thank you
Filip!

Comment: Something I always wanted to know.

Comment: Its kind of joke, or? I do not understand :D

Comment: Nah, what I was saying was that I always wanted to know how to do this, never found a solution.

Comment: Oh, we are both ..... :D

Answer (score 0):

> Main reasons behind SSL Certificate Error on Google Chrome are:
>
> **(1) The System Time is not the real-time.**
>
> (2) The SSL certificate has Expired.
>
> (3) Google Chrome is not updated.
>
> (4) The SSL certificate is not Installed properly.
>
> (5) The SSL certificate is not issued by a Trusted Certificate
>   Authority (CA) or a self-signed certificate is used to secure a
>   website.
>
> (6) The website is secured with an outdated 128-bit SSL.
>
> (7) The website is secured with an outdated SHA-1 Algorithm.

https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/google-chrome-ssl-certificate-errors-troubleshoot-guide/

For SSL certificate without subdomain, use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hello. First of all, thank you! As I just checked, the problem is not only in google chrome. When I write "www" before domain, it always show error. If  I write it without "www", it works.

Comment: Your certificate is only valid without www ?

Comment: Thank you! Your htaccess modification works for www. But when I type my domain without www and without https it shows me path in the url and 404 Error.

https://elodywedding.com/domains/elodywedding.com/

Comment: You have a problem with your certificate, because we can read: Error code : sec_error_unknown_issuer

Comment: Yes. It's possible. But isn't there any way how to modify your htaccess code in order not show all path to directory, where is site ?

Comment: This problem is not in the htaccess. But in your configuration for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: @Croises a bit different, this one.